# Prevent event only if value is false and include custom Bulma extension in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vuejs2, bulma

1. I want to prevent click event on checkbox, only if value is false.
   Is there way to do it inline like im trying?
   `<input type="checkbox" v-model="task.done" :checked="task.done" @click.prevent="value">`
2. I using Vue.js v2 (webpack template) and i dont know how to include [Bulma slider](https://wikiki.github.io/bulma-extensions/slider) in my project (probably script tag, but where?).
   I installed it with npm command: `npm install bulma-slider --save`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can check if value is false, and call `.preventDefault()`. Change your HTML to:

   `<input type="checkbox" v-model="task.done" @click="onClick)">`

and

```
methods: {
  onClick(event) {
    if (event.target.value === false) event.preventDefault()
  }
}
```

2. You can try to use this: https://github.com/vue-bulma/slider

Comment: I was thinking about first approach and probably gonna use it like that. About second one i want extension that i installed, but thanks for linking that.